# How to pivot specific columns while grouping other columns (SQL)

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, data-manipulation, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I am working on a SQL query in Azure Databricks Environment, where considering the following dataset:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tb_user_info
(
  clientid  INT,
  visitid  STRING,
  channel  STRING,
  conversion INT,
  index INT,
  value STRING
);

INSERT INTO tb_user_info VALUES
  (123, 'abc123', 'google', 1, 11, '1250'),
  (123, 'abc123', 'google', 1, 22, '25000'),
  (123, 'abc123', 'google', 1, 33, '1K and 3K'),
  (456, 'def456', 'facebook', 3, 11, '2860'),
  (456, 'def456', 'facebook', 3, 22, '78000'),  
  (456, 'def456', 'facebook', 3, 33, '3K and 5K');

SELECT * FROM tb_user_info ORDER BY clientid, index
```

| clientid | visitid | channel | conversion | index | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | abc123 | google | 1 | 11 | 1250 |
| 123 | abc123 | google | 1 | 22 | 25000 |
| 123 | abc123 | google | 1 | 33 | 1K and 3k |
| 456 | def456 | facebook | 3 | 11 | 2860 |
| 456 | def456 | facebook | 3 | 22 | 78000 |
| 456 | def456 | facebook | 3 | 33 | 3K and 5k |

I want to get the following output:

| clientid | visitid | channel | conversion | salary (index=11) | savings (index=22) | salary range (index=33) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | abc123 | google | 1 | 1250 | 25000 | 1K and 3k |
| 456 | def456 | facebook | 1 | 2860 | 78000 | 3K and 5k |

where the columns **clientid**, **visitid**, **channel** and **conversion** are grouped and the columns **index** and **value** are the columns that are pivoted.

I've tried using the [Pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-pivot) function and I read this [Documentation](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2018/11/01/sql-pivot-converting-rows-to-columns.html) but I haven't been successful.

Could you help me with how can I solve this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what actual problem you have encounted, I write one query, it seems work normally,

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT clientid, visitid ,  channel , conversion , ind ,  value
  FROM tb_user_info
) ss
PIVOT (
  max(value)
  FOR ind in (
   [11] ,[22] ,[33]
  )
) as a
```